# Unable to Find Webpage Element in Form using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to enter text into the Address search field on this website - https://www.verizon.com/business/products/internet/#lq

[image]

From the inspection, the element appears to be in a form that I am not familiar with accessing using the XPATH. Here is the code snippet I am currently attempting; I've tried multiple IDs with no success -

```py
driver.get("https://www.verizon.com/business/products/internet/#lq")
time.sleep(5)
address_input5 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='cln96qoj400be35cyp7u0ckuz']")))
address_input5.clear()
address_input5.send_keys(address)
address_input5.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
```

And the inspection snippet -

[image]

Should I be using a different method than XPATH to select this element?

**UPDATE #2**

````
#.gTCII .form-group input[name="lq-widget-street-Address"]

address_input5 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="lq-widget-street-Address"]')))
address_input5 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[data-testid="test-input"]')))```
````

Comment: It looks like `cln96qoj400be35cyp7u0ckuz` is a randomly-generated id, and it changes every time the page loads.  You can't use that to search for the element.

Comment: Best practice is to remove any hard sleeps, e.g. `time.sleep(5)`, and replace them with `WebDriverWait`s. In the first case, you have a hard sleep followed by a proper wait which just makes the hard sleep redundant. Hard sleeps don't wait an "intelligent" amount of time... they always wait X seconds even if the element is already ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `"css selector"`, `'input[data-testid="test-input"]'`, to locate that input field.

The CSS selector is cleaner and not a changing auto-generated selector. It's easy to verify in the console output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this will help greatly locating elements. I am still unable to select the box using the code snippets shown in update 2. The CSS selector seems to be the "lq-widget-street-Address", do I also need to specify .gTCII and .form-group to access this field?

Comment: Simplify your selectors down to something like `input[name="lq-widget-street-Address"]`. The autogenerated classnames like `gTCII` could change, and therefore shouldn't be included with your selector assuming your selector is unique enough to match on that one element.

Comment: I found the issue. The input[name="lq-widget-street-Address"] seems to be working,but only if i click the search box before it times out. Seems to not be loading the CSS selector until the box is selected. Is there anyway to circumvent this?

Comment: That should be OK. When I was testing selenium on that website, I had to click on that box first before entering text.

Comment: Is there a way to select this box without having to manually click it? Having to manually intervene defeats the purpose of the script.

Comment: I was referring to a `selenium` `.click()` action. I'll create a script and add it in here...

Comment: After finding the element: `element = driver.find_element('input[name="lq-widget-street-Address"]')` then you can do this: `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();arguments[0].value='1 main st'", element)`

Comment: This is working! Now I am trying to figure out how to enter the address entered by the user instead of the "1 main street". When I just attempt to click I get a "element not interactable" error.
`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", address_input5)
address_input5.send_keys(address)`

Comment: It would use `arguments[1]` for the next arg. Eg. `address = "100 Summer St"` and then `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", element, address)`

Comment: Thanks again!

This works-
`address_input5 = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="lq-widget-street-Address"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", address_input5, address)'